# "Error: connect ENETUNREACH 127.0.0.1:5432 - Local (0.0.0.0:0)" while trying to set up db tables; Docker on Ubuntu wsl

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm very new to docker and ubuntu, but my new job required it.
I am currently setting up the environment, after installing WSl and docker on windows 10. I cloned the repo into docker on ubuntu and had to run 3 database systems in the db directory using the codes below.

I'm running node version- 12.13.1 for this project

```
For Postgres;
docker build -t wad-db . --build-arg USER_ID=1000 --build-arg GROUP_ID=1000

docker run -p 5432:5432 --restart always -e POSTGRES_USER=pguser -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=docker -e PGDATA=/home/postgres/data -e POSTGRES_DB=wad -it -d wad-db
```

```
For Redis
docker run -p 6379:6379 --restart always -it -d redis
```

```
For RabbitMQ
docker run -p 5672:5672 --restart always -it -d rabbitmq
```

```
I installed this globally;
npm install -g @microsoft/rush pm2 typescript webpack webpack-cli @mapbox/node-pre-gyp
```

Then ran

```
rush update & rush build  to build the package
```

Finally, I had to run

```
node index.js safe-init dev
and then 
node index.js seed dev
```

in the db directory to init the database
Everything else goes smoothly until I run

```
node index.js safe-init dev
```

I get the following error;

```
Error: connect ENETUNREACH 127.0.0.1:5432 - Local (0.0.0.0:0)
    at internalConnect (net.js:908:16)
    at defaultTriggerAsyncIdScope (internal/async_hooks.js:301:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.emitLookup [as callback] (net.js:1051:9)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:65:10) {
  errno: 'ENETUNREACH',
  code: 'ENETUNREACH',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 5432
}
```

I have searched the entire internet for solutions, still nothing. Any help will be greatly appreciated. I think it has something to do with the port 5432, but being my first time with linux, I don't know what I could be doing wrong, or how todebug this.